# How to cancel http_request if client aborts in cpprestsdk?

Tags: c++, sockets, cpprest-sdk

I'm using http_listener to handle http requests from clients.

The listener can only process limited requests in the same time, so some of the requests doesn't get a chance to be processed before its client peer aborts.
In that case, I do not want the listener process the requests whose client has already been aborted.

Is there a way I can determinate this against http_request?

Comment: Hi, have you found any solution to this problem?